# Where can I find Euro Truck Simulator 2's document folder on Mac?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I can‘t find the „Euro Truck Simulator 2“ documents folder in library support on mac and either from the stream.

Where is it on Mac?

Comment: If it is a sandboxed application it would be in the 'Library/Containers' folder in your home directory

Answer (score 1):

The Euro Truck Simulator 2 configuration, savedata and mods are located on `~/Library/Application Support/Euro Truck Simulator 2`.

[image]

If you are looking for Steam Cloud profiles, go to `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/userdata/<Internal Steam ID>/227300/remote`.

[image]